# How do I test the default option is displayed on a dropdown - cypress

Tags: dropdown, cypress, assert

I'm trying to assert that the default option "AUTO" is displayed on the following dropdown.

```js
<select id="wifi2.4">
<option class="" value="" >AUTO</option>
<option value="0">1 - 2412 MHz</option>
<option value="1">2 - 2417 MHz</option>
<option value="2">3 - 2422 MHz</option>
<option value="3">4 - 2427 MHz</option>
</select>
```

I have tried the following:

```js
cy.get('div.medium-2:nth-child(2) > select:nth-child(1)').should('have.value', 'AUTO')
```

But this is returning [...to have value 'AUTO', but the value was '' ] and using 'have.text...' just returns all the options in the list.

would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction :-)

Answer (score 1):

The select element displays text on the page that's not easily accessible through javascript. Essentially, it is showing the text of the option it's `selectedIndex` property is pointing to (which is initially 0).

The simplest way to assert "AUTO" is displayed is to target the selected option and verify it's text.

```js
cy.get('select[id="wifi2.4"] option:selected')  // which option is selected?
  .invoke('text')                               // get it's text
  .should('eq', 'AUTO')                         // verify it's the right one

cy.get('select[id="wifi2.4"]')
  .select('2')                                  // select something else

cy.get('select[id="wifi2.4"] option:selected')  // which option is selected?
  .invoke('text')                               // get it's text
  .should('eq', '3 - 2422 MHz')                 // verify it's the right one
```

Note the id `wifi2.4` is a bit tricky to use in `cy.get()` because the shorthand way

```
cy.get('#wifi2.4')             // fails to find the element!
```

is telling Cypress to find the id `wifi2` with a class `4`, so you should use the long-hand way I've shown above.

Answer (score 0):

So the reason it is returning that error message is because it has no value. It is just an empty string as shown in the HTML. So the best way I have found to make assertions on the options that don't have the `selected="selected"` is this right here. MDN provides the information on how the selected option shows up first if it doesn't have the `selected` attribute. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

```
cy.get('#wifi2.4')
  .children()
  .first()
  .then(option1 => {
    expect(option1).to.be.selected;
});
```

This gets the id of the select, gets the first child, takes that and asserts that it shows up as selected.

Answer (score 0):

If you see in your HTML code, the value attribute is empty and this is mentioned in the error that you're getting. So changing to `have.text` should solve the issue.

```
cy.get(select#wifi2.4).children().first().should('have.text', 'AUTO')
```

`Children()` gets the children of each DOM element within a set of DOM elements. `first()` gets the first DOM element within a set of DOM elements.